# Java 8 any good rounding algorithm to round the bigdecimal and return total value as 100

Tags: java, sorting

I am currently looking for a good algorithm which will do the rounding and return the total value as 100. The variable type is BigDecimal.

I have to return the BigDecimal in 2 digit format e.g. 10.10

The result should be something like this:

List will have

18.56, 20.96, 18.56, 19.16 and 22.75.

Total of 18.56 + 20.96 + 18.56 + 19.16 + 22.75 should be 100.00

The rounding when done with these values should be very close to the original value. Must be as accurate as possible.

This will not be the only scenario there could be 3 ,4, 5, 6 upto 10 variables.

Any help will be appreciated.

1. I did the rounding of the arraylist.
2. Added all the values
3. Checked the difference
4. Now I am planning to reverse rounded sorting array and subtract the difference from first and 2nd so that it is equal to 100.

I am not very sure how good this algorithm is but I would really appreciate if you have any better idea.

```
 @Test
    public void roundDecimalValuesAndCalculateTotalToHundredPercent() {
        BigDecimal no1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(18.562874251497007);
        BigDecimal no2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(20.958083832335326);
        BigDecimal no3 = BigDecimal.valueOf(18.562874251497007);
        BigDecimal no4 = BigDecimal.valueOf(19.161676646706585);
        BigDecimal no5 = BigDecimal.valueOf(22.75449101796407);
        List<BigDecimal> value = Arrays.asList(no1, no2, no3, no4, no5);


        scaleAndPrintList(value);
    }


    private void scaleAndPrintList(List<BigDecimal> list) {
        list.forEach(bigDecimal -> {
            System.out.println("Number is " + bigDecimal + ", ROUND_CEILING - " + bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING) + ", ROUND_HALF_UP - " + bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
        });

        list = list.stream()
                .map(bigDecimal -> bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        final BigDecimal reduce = list.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

        System.out.println("Addition " + reduce);

        // This is the error.
        final BigDecimal difference = BigDecimal.valueOf(100).subtract(reduce);

        System.out.println("Difference - " + difference);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends, how do you want to sacrifice precision of members.
To do it in 1 pass, and spread the error across members, I would collect (rounded/dropped) part of each member and keep sum of rounded, than add dropped delta of previous to the next one before rounding. The last member must be calculated like this: `100 - (summ of prev)` - which will be already rounded to 2 digits.

```java
private static void scaleAndPrintList(List<BigDecimal> list) {
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
    BigDecimal delta = BigDecimal.valueOf(0);
    for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++) {
        BigDecimal bd = list.get(i);
        BigDecimal res = bd.add(delta).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("Number " + bd + " => " + res + "   diff: " + bd.subtract(res));
        delta = bd.subtract(res);
        sum = sum.add(res);
    }
    // Last member
    BigDecimal bd = list.get(list.size()-1);
    BigDecimal res = BigDecimal .valueOf(100).subtract(sum);
    System.out.println("Last Number " + bd + " => " + res + "   diff: " + bd.subtract(res));
}
```

Output:

```
Number 18.564474251497007 => 18.56   diff: 0.004474251497007
Number 20.954483832335328 => 20.96   diff: -0.005516167664672
Number 18.562874251497007 => 18.56   diff: 0.002874251497007
Number 19.161676646706585 => 19.16   diff: 0.001676646706585
Last Number 22.75449101796407 => 22.76   diff: -0.00550898203593
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I never though about the difference. I was trying for following scenario:

```
BigDecimal no1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(60.33334);
BigDecimal no2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(40.38989);
The result for this scenario comes as follows:
Number 60.33334 => 60.33   diff: 0.00334
Last Number 40.38989 => 39.67   diff: 0.71989
Actual difference is -0.72 the expected result was 60 and 40
```

Instead of just subtracting from last member. We can loop over list and minus the values after the decimal point first.